# Callback url not approved despite being provided Twitter Api

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, twitter-oauth

In the twitter console I have a callback url from firebase linked. Yet when I try to authenticate using twitter I get the error:

```
"Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors> (code (null))
```

Whats going on? I have tried everything , and no one else on the internet seems to have this issue but me?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue today. Did you check this ? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/callback_url.html

Comment: Update.. issue resolve for me, I just followed the link I gave before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**I face same issue we no need to change in code side, we just need to change some setting in developer account of twitter (tested solution)**

You need to add the consumer/api key in **Callback URL** using below format

Ref link : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/callback_url.html

twitterkit-**consumer/api key**://

[image]

You need to add **twitterkit-yourConsumerKey** in **info.plist**

```
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>twitterkit-your Consumer Key (API Key)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Was having an issue similar issue after the policy update of Twitter. Should be accepted as correct answer.

Comment: @Zack. Please if the answer solve your question can you accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So heres what worked for me. I used the regular old twitter Kit ( for swift and objective c ) given on twitters GitHub here:

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki

This solved my call back url problems ( I was originally using Alamofire )

This is a good example of an error free network call :

```
 let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"

    var clientError : NSError?

    let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", urlString: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: ["user_id": "\(currentProfileTwitterUid)"], error: &clientError)

    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if connectionError != nil {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: connectionError))")
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? Any{

            if let dict = json as? [String : Any]{
                //print(json)


            }
            }



        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else!